# Facebook insights - FQL API

Tags: statistics, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

We currently have several send buttons on our website and for each one we use a different reference for the 'fb_ref' field so we know where the message originated.

Im looking for a way to obtain the statistics from facebook to see how many messages were sent each day from each of the buttons.

This information is held by facebook insights, so far I can see that by using the FQL API we can   query the graph to find out how many times the send button was used but this occurs on a per domain level (using the 'domain_widget_send_clicks' metric)

From the information in the public domain I do not see how I can request the information per 'fb_ref' even though this will be held in the database.

Will the result be delivered automatically on a per 'fb_ref' level or as one total for the domain. To obtain the stats on a per 'fb_ref' level do we need to perform a separate query for each reference, if so what is the metric we use.

If this is a case of trial and error then we will continue however if anyone has tackled this one before I would appreciate your comments.

The details for the insight metrics can be seen here:
This can be seen here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/